# why the branch does not appear to be a git repository? it is not the master branch

Tags: bash, git, heroku

I don't know what I did something to change the configuration of the git setting.
When I use 'git push **dev** master', there is an error below, but this instruction is working before.

```sh
$ git push dev master
fatal: 'dev' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

This is the setting and configuration of my repository and branches

```sh
$ git remote -v
origin https://git.heroku.com/main_project.git (fetch)
origin https://git.heroku.com/main_project.git (push)

$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://git.heroku.com/main_project.git
  Push  URL: https://git.heroku.com/main_project.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    backup                           tracked
    dev                              tracked
    development                      tracked
    master                           tracked
    refs/remotes/origin/fullcalendar stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)
    repeat_reminders                 tracked
    stable                           tracked
    weekly                           tracked
  Local branches configured for 'git pull':
    dev    merges with remote dev
    master merges with remote dev
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    dev    pushes to dev    (up to date)
    master pushes to master (up to date)

$ git branch -a
  dev
* master
  remotes/origin/backup
  remotes/origin/dev
  remotes/origin/development
  remotes/origin/fullcalendar
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/origin/repeat_reminders
  remotes/origin/stable
  remotes/origin/weekly
```

I searched for some solutions such as 'set-url' or add origin, such below
But they are not working either.

```sh
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/dev master

git remote add origin https://git.heroku.com/dev.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

Please help this questions.
Thank you very much.

Comment: The argument to `git push` are: (1) the name of the *other Git*, such as `origin`, and then (2) the *list of branches and/or other references you wish to send to that other Git*. If you want to supply a list of branches, you must first supply the name of the other Git.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? First, you have a single remote called `origin` set up. When you run `git push dev master` you are asking git to push a local branch called master into a remote branch with the same name on a remote that is called `dev`. Given that you only have `origin` set up, don't expect git to be able to comply. If what you want to do is push two branches, namely dev and master, to origin, you should run:

```
git push origin dev master
```

If what you want to do is push your local dev branch to the remote master branch, you should do

```
git push origin dev:master
```

Or is there anything else you are trying to do?

Comment: Can I remove the origin to ensure 'git push dev master' working? Because this instruction is working before. If so, how can I remove the origin?

Comment: YOu could add a different remote called dev: `git remote add dev the-url`... or you could rename it if that's the remote that is now called `origin`: `git remote rename origin dev`